# While editing an entry there is no "expand" icon anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am just wondering whether it is a bug in the new CSS or not. While editing come entry there  is no "expand" icon anymore:

New design:
[image]

Old design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Great, thank you!